# program for undertsanding how input and output stream buffers actually work

Tags: c++, buffer

I am new to C++. So, i was trying out the following program. And I'm having a trouble understanding why is it showing me the corresponding output when I'm

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ios>

// for numeric_limits 
#include<limits>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int num1;
    float num2;

    cin >> num1;
    //cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cin >> num2;
    cout << num1 << num2;
}
```

For now the output is

```
5.6     <-- input
50.6
```

here it is not even taking the num2 input.

But after i uncomment the cin.ignore line, it is showing the perfect output

```
5.6     <--num1
9.8     <--num2
59.8
```

Can anyone explain me how is it working from scratch, and how the operating system is involved in buffer creation?

Comment: Just a general tip: When printing numbers (and most other things), put a delimitor between them. You would have spotted what happened much easier yourself if `cout << num1 << num2;` was instead `cout << num1 << ", " << num2;`

Answer (score 0):

num1 is int, so the first thing read from the stream into the num1 variable is `5`, the reading stop at first nondigit character, which is the dot `.`.

Then num2 is being read and it is float. `.6` reads as `0.6`.

The output is `5` followed by `0.6` without any character in between.

When you uncomment cin.ignore(), the same thing happens, except before you read num2, all characters up to next newline (including) are discarded.

You read `5` into num1, discard `.6\n` and then read `9.8` into num2 variable, since it is the first thing after newline character.

Then you output `5` followed by `9.8` without any character in between them.